# Loops with random sampling from a matrix and distance calculation

Tags: r, loops, matrix, random, sample

I got a list of nodes, and I need to randomly assign 'p' hubs to 'n' clients.

I got the following data, where the first row shows:

- The total number of nodes.
- The requested number of hubs.
- The total supply capacity for each hub.

The following lines show:

- The first column the node number.
- The second column the "x" coordinate.
- The third the "y" coordinate.

Below I will show the raw data, adding `colnames()` it would look something like this:

```
total_nodes hubs_required  total_capacity
    50           5              120

node number x_coordinate y_coordinate  node_demand
   1            2           62            3
   2           80           25           14
   3           36           88            1
   4           57           23           14
   .            .            .            .
   .            .            .            .
   .            .            .            .
   50           1           58            2
```

The x and y values are provided so we can calculate the Euclidean distance.

```
nodes:

 50 5 120
 1 2 62 3
 2 80 25 14
 3 36 88 1
 4 57 23 14
 5 33 17 19
 6 76 43 2
 7 77 85 14
 8 94 6 6
 9 89 11 7
 10 59 72 6
 11 39 82 10
 12 87 24 18
 13 44 76 3
 14 2 83 6
 15 19 43 20
 16 5 27 4
 17 58 72 14
 18 14 50 11
 19 43 18 19
 20 87 7 15
 21 11 56 15
 22 31 16 4
 23 51 94 13
 24 55 13 13
 25 84 57 5
 26 12 2 16
 27 53 33 3
 28 53 10 7
 29 33 32 14
 30 69 67 17
 31 43 5 3
 32 10 75 3
 33 8 26 12
 34 3 1 14
 35 96 22 20
 36 6 48 13
 37 59 22 10
 38 66 69 9
 39 22 50 6
 40 75 21 18
 41 4 81 7
 42 41 97 20
 43 92 34 9
 44 12 64 1
 45 60 84 8
 46 35 100 5
 47 38 2 1
 48 9 9 7
 49 54 59 9
 50 1 58 2
```

I extracted the information from the first line.

```
nodes <- as.matrix(read.table(data))
header<-colnames(nodes)
clean_header <-gsub('X','',header)
requested_hubs <- as.numeric(clean_header[2])
max_supply_capacity <- as.numeric(clean_header[3])
```

I need to **randomly** select 5 nodes, that will act as hubs

```
set.seed(37)
node_to_hub <-nodes[sample(nrow(nodes),requested_hubs,replace = FALSE),]
```

Then **randomly** I need to assign nodes to each hub calculate the distances between the hub and each one of the nodes and when the `max_supply_capacity`(120) is exceeded select the following hub and repeat the process.

After the final iteration I need to return the cumulative sum of distances for all the hubs.

I need to repeat this process 100 times and return the `min()` value of the cumulative sum of distances.

This is where I'm completely stuck since I'm not sure how to loop through a matrix let alone when I have to select elements randomly.

I got the following elements:

```
capacity <- c(numeric()) # needs to be <= to 120
distance_sum <- c(numeric())
global_hub_distance <- c(numeric())
```

The formula  for the euclidean distance (rounded) would be as below but I'm not sure how I can reflect the random selection when assigning nodes.

`distance <-round(sqrt(((node_to_hub[i,2]-nodes[i,2]))^2+(node_to_hub[random,3]-nodes[random,3])^2))`

The idea for the loop I think I need is below, but as I mentioned before I don't know how to deal with the sample client selection, and the distance calculation of the random clients.

```
    for(i in 1:100){
    node_to_hub
    for(i in 1:nrow(node_to_hub){
#Should I randomly sample the clients here???
    while(capacity < 120){ 
    node_demand <- nodes[**random**,3] 
    distance <-round(sqrt(((node_to_hub[i,2]-nodes[i,2]))^2+(node_to_hub[**random**,3]-nodes[**random**,3])^2))
    capacity <-c(capacity, node_demand)
    distance_sum <- c(distance_sum,distance)
}
global_hub_distance <- c(global_hub_distance,distance_sum)
capacity <- 0 
distance_sum <- 0 
}
min(global_hub_distance)
}
```

Comment: Can you redo your example data formatting for us? maybe paste the data as the results of ```dput(data)``` ? I'm having trouble understanding your data (especially that first row with the 50)

Comment: Hi Evan, I have modified my post, hopefully it will be a bit clearer.

Comment: The data is clearer but your objective is not quite clear. Be concise but clearer. You have nodes, you select 5 at random and call them hubs. Then ... for each hub, you get the distance to every node? Up until you hit the node that raises the cumulative total over 120? It isn't clear from reading what you want. Can you refine it?

Comment: Randomly select 5 different nodes, these become hubs with capacity of 120.
Randomly assign 'client' nodes to each until demand exceeds capacity.
Calculate distances from each hub to each 'client' node and add them up.
Keep this value in a variable that keeps track of the distances for each iteration.
Repeat this process 100 times and then select the min value out of the variable that keeps track of the distances.
I hope this is clearer, please let me know if more clarification is needed, we weren't given much more information so it took me a while to figure out what was needed!

Comment: This is much clearer. My answer flips capacity and distance so I'll have to rework it. What's this for might I ask? I presume it's some UK power/gas analyst work?

Comment: It's actually for a data analysis course, the subject is called METAHEURISTICS, but this is WAY too different from any other of the subjects I have done. The second part is working on this problem but using Tabu Search and Genetic algorithms which I think is a bit crazy for people that have no Computer Science background.
Many many thanks for your help Evan!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173101/discussion-between-evan-friedland-and-sergi).

Comment: Just to follow up because I caught something - do you mean to randomly sort REMAINING nodes? / and NOT include nodes used as hubs?

Comment: Yes, ideally, although that has been a point of confusion for many since it isn't very clear in the problem description. To me if a node becomes a hub then it cannot become a client of another hub.

Comment: And then 2 hubs can share a node?

Comment: Yes nodes can be connected to  diferent hubs :)

Comment: I tried using:
`nodes[-hubs,]`
But I get this error:
`Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'`

Comment: I have working code for it on my comp but wont be able to send it for 6 hours or so ~

Comment: Oh that's great! No problem at all, I can work on other problems in the meantime. Many thanks Evan.

Comment: See my edit - i made it a function for fun ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not EXACTLY sure what you are looking for but this code may be able to help you. It's not extremely fast, as instead of using a while to stop after hitting your total_capacity it just does a cumsum on the full node list and find the place where you exceed 120.

```
nodes <- structure(list(node_number = 1:50, 
               x = c(2L, 80L, 36L, 57L, 33L, 76L, 77L, 94L, 
                     89L, 59L, 39L, 87L, 44L, 2L, 19L, 5L, 
                     58L, 14L, 43L, 87L, 11L, 31L, 51L, 55L, 
                     84L, 12L, 53L, 53L, 33L, 69L, 43L, 10L, 
                     8L, 3L, 96L, 6L, 59L, 66L, 22L, 75L, 4L, 
                     41L, 92L, 12L, 60L, 35L, 38L, 9L, 54L, 1L), 
               y = c(62L, 25L, 88L, 23L, 17L, 43L, 85L, 6L, 11L, 
                     72L, 82L, 24L, 76L, 83L, 43L, 27L, 72L, 50L, 
                     18L, 7L, 56L, 16L, 94L, 13L, 57L, 2L, 33L, 10L, 
                     32L, 67L, 5L, 75L, 26L, 1L, 22L, 48L, 22L, 69L,
                     50L, 21L, 81L, 97L, 34L, 64L, 84L, 100L, 2L, 9L, 59L, 58L), 
               node_demand = c(3L, 14L, 1L, 14L, 19L, 2L, 14L, 6L, 
                               7L, 6L, 10L, 18L, 3L, 6L, 20L, 4L, 
                               14L, 11L, 19L,  15L, 15L, 4L, 13L, 
                               13L, 5L, 16L, 3L, 7L, 14L, 17L, 
                               3L, 3L, 12L, 14L, 20L, 13L, 10L, 
                               9L, 6L, 18L, 7L, 20L, 9L, 1L, 8L, 
                               5L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 2L)), 
          .Names = c("node_number", "x", "y", "node_demand"), 
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -50L))

total_nodes = nrow(nodes)
hubs_required = 5
total_capacity = 120
iterations <- 100
track_sums <- matrix(NA, nrow = iterations, ncol = hubs_required)
colnames(track_sums) <- paste0("demand_at_hub",1:hubs_required)
```

And then I prefer using a function for distance, in this case A and B are 2 separate vectors with c(x,y) and c(x,y).

```
euc.dist <- function(A, B) round(sqrt(sum((A - B) ^ 2))) # distances
```

The Loop:

```
for(i in 1:iterations){
  # random hub selection
  hubs <- nodes[sample(1:total_nodes, hubs_required, replace = FALSE),]
  for(h in 1:hubs_required){
    # sample the nodes into a random order
    random_nodes <- nodes[sample(1:nrow(nodes), size = nrow(nodes), replace = FALSE),]
    # cumulative sum their demand, and get which number passes 120, 
    # and subtract 1 to get the node before that
    last <- which(cumsum(random_nodes$node_demand) > total_capacity) [1] - 1
    # get sum of all distances to those nodes (1 though the last)
     all_distances <- apply(random_nodes[1:last,], 1, function(rn) {
      euc.dist(A = hubs[h,c("x","y")], 
               B = rn[c("x","y")]) 
    })
    track_sums[i,h] <- sum(all_distances)
  }
}

min(rowSums(track_sums))
```

**EDIT**

as a function:

```
hubnode <- function(nodes, hubs_required = 5, total_capacity = 120, iterations = 10){
  # initialize results matrices
  track_sums <- node_count <- matrix(NA, nrow = iterations, ncol = hubs_required)
  colnames(track_sums) <- paste0("demand_at_hub",1:hubs_required)
  colnames(node_count) <- paste0("nodes_at_hub",1:hubs_required)
  # user defined distance function (only exists wihtin hubnode() function)
  euc.dist <- function(A, B) round(sqrt(sum((A - B) ^ 2))) 

  for(i in 1:iterations){
    # random hub selection
    assigned_hubs <- sample(1:nrow(nodes), hubs_required, replace = FALSE)
    hubs <- nodes[assigned_hubs,]
    assigned_nodes <- NULL
    for(h in 1:hubs_required){
      # sample the nodes into a random order
      assigned_nodes <- sample((1:nrow(nodes))[-assigned_hubs], replace = FALSE)
      random_nodes <- nodes[assigned_nodes,]
      # cumulative sum their demand, and get which number passes 120, 
      # and subtract 1 to get the node before that
      last <- which(cumsum(random_nodes$node_demand) > total_capacity) [1] - 1
      # if there are none
      if(is.na(last)) last = nrow(random_nodes)
      node_count[i,h] <- last
      # get sum of all distances to those nodes (1 though the last)
      all_distances <- apply(random_nodes[1:last,], 1, function(rn) {
        euc.dist(A = hubs[h,c("x","y")], 
                 B = rn[c("x","y")]) 
      })
      track_sums[i,h] <- sum(all_distances)
    }
  }
  return(list(track_sums = track_sums, node_count = node_count))
}

output <- hubnode(nodes, iterations = 100)

node_count <- output$node_count
track_sums <- output$track_sums

plot(rowSums(node_count),  
     rowSums(track_sums), xlab = "Node Count", ylab = "Total Demand", main = paste("Result of", 100, "iterations"))

min(rowSums(track_sums))
```

Comment: Woops I summed up distance not capacity, give me a moment

Comment: Amazing, many thanks. I actually need to create a function for the next variation of this exercise using tabu search so the structure is clearer now.